# Validate matching array keys

Tags: php, arrays, validation

Given the following arrays how can I elegantly validate that option, price and cost arrays have matching key values?

```
Array
(
    [option] => Array
        (
            [1] => C
            [2] => M
            [3] => G
        )

    [price] => Array
        (
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 200
            [3] => 300
        )

    [cost] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
        )
)
```

I thought of running a **foreach(array as key => values)** on each array and sending those values to another array, and then using **if(!in_array)**, but theres got to be a better way to do it.

Comment: What would constitute a match?  For example, if `option` had `[1] => 100`, would that be a match for `price`? What if option instead had `[2] => 100`? `cost` has 3 0's--is that a match?  This question may be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the same keys as there is no correlation with the values in the array.  If so, you can run a diff on the keys of each sub-array:

```
if(call_user_func_array('array_diff_key', $array)) {
    // not the same keys
} else {
    // same keys
}
```

- `call_user_func_array()` takes the array as an array of arguments and passes each to `array_diff_key()`
- If the result is not empty then there are differences
- If the result is empty then there are no differences

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an array in this way:

```
Array
(
    [option] => Array
        (
            [C] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 100
                    [cost] => 0
                )

            [M] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 200
                    [cost] => 0
                )

            [G] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 300
                    [cost] => 0
                )

        )
)
```

PHP Code:

```
$product = array("option" => array("C" => array("price" => 100, "cost" => 0), "M" => array("price" => 200, "cost" => 0), "G" => array("price" => 300, "cost" => 0)));
```

Comment: How is this related to the question? Why would I use this structure?

Comment: This structure is more convienent if you have certain options like C, M, and G with a different price and cost and I thought that was your idea. I'm sorry if I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: But you dont know the context where the array is used. There is a reason the array has the structure described.